# Shell script to copy files from one location to another

Tags: python, macos, shell

I'm developing on a MAC and I'm very new to scripting on a MAC.

Basically I'd like to have a script that can copy files from one location to another so I can run it in the terminal rather than having to copy the files manually. So, I wonder if anyone out there can provide me with a script that;-

Checks the content of the destination folder against that of the source folder and where there is a difference, copies the files from the source folder to the destination folder.

```
                 -OR IF THAT IS NOT POSSIBLE-
```

a script that simply copies files from one location to another.

Comment: I am also developping and also want this tool, thanks

Comment: Umm, these scripts you're asking for aren't scripts, they're basic commands. Like, say, `ditto` or `cp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Sorry about the post. I found a far better way to achieve what I wanted to do.

Essentially I am doing frontend development for mobile phone apps, so I have a local repository where the frontend files sit and a number of other directories for the core app code for each device (ios, iphone, blackberry e.t.c). So i needed a way to copy updated files from the frontend directory to each core mobile app directory. Turns out symbolic links are a far better approach and remove the need for the script/command to copy files from one directory to another.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `rsync`.

```
$ rsync -av source target
```

Comment: +1. There are many powerful options. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/rsync.1.html . Read about --delete for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.  This script will check for the existence in dir2 for all files that are present in dir1.  If thee file is not present in dir2, then it will copy the file to dir2.

```
for file in dir1; do 
    if [ ! -s dir2/$file ] ; then 
        cp $file dir2/$file 
    fi 
done
```